# ssh-agent fails to remember password

Tags: ssh-agent

```
ssh me@server
eval $(ssh-agent);
set | grep SSH_A
 SSH_AGENT_PID=19216
 SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-CYiyq19215/agent.19215
ssh-add
 Enter passphrase for /home/me/.ssh/id_rsa: 
 Identity added: /home/me/.ssh/id_rsa (/home/me/.ssh/id_rsa)
ssh-add -l
 2048 8f:bf:61:e5:f2:bc:bc:c2:57:9e:03:8e:d1:b3:28:93 /home/me/.ssh/id_rsa (RSA)
ssh x@other server
 Enter passphrase for key '/home/me/.ssh/id_rsa':
```

I would have expected that the password for my `id_rsa` file was saved, so I would not need to re-type it again.

It works fine for a different user on that server, but I don't see what is different. Any clue?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that if you have no public key, you'll get this behaviour.

Note that it asks for a password, but if you press  it is ok too. (if you type a bad password, it is not ok though)

As soon as I copied the corresponding public key to the server, I was not asked for passphrase any more